# java import for HttpConnection

Tags: blackberry, java-me

My code has an error that says HttpConnection cannot be resolved.  The documentation says it is in the javax.microedition.io package, so I tried:

```
import javax.microedition.io;
```

That results in an error stating only a type can be resolved.   Using quick fix results in:

```
 import javax.microedition.io.*;
```

I’m assuming something is wrong with the imports?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code where you are using HttpConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second import should solve your problem with resolving [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html).    However, HttpConnection is an interface.   Are you using it as a class?

Comment: Hi,Yes I am using it as a class, got code from book, looks like the auther has some errors in his code